# how can I play a sound with pygame while the system is waiting?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm using the pygame function pygame.time.delay() to make pygame freeze while presenting some pictures or text, and  I want to play a sound at the same time.

The problem, I think, is that in order for pygame mixer to work the main loop must be running, so putting the system on wait it also stops the mixer.

Any easy way to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.time.delay()` is a bad idea for waiting while presenting things, it not only will prevent you from playing music it can also freeze your screen (blank screen).

You should process events and update the display although you have static image.

Some alternatives are:

1. Use a counter in your loop to know how long you should keep the same image in the screen.
2. Use a [timer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to receive a User Event that will notify you that you need to change the current state.

Comment: thanks,
the solution (1) is what I thought about and what I used to do with another script that I made... my worry was that the control of the timing was not as precise as using the pygame.time.delay() command..
do you think that the function fpsClock.tick(FPS) is precise enough to force your loop running at ms precision, so that I can just compute the number of cycles that update the counter until the wanted delay is met?

Comment: You shouldn't trust `fpsClock.Tick(FPS)` to be exact, but it should be accurate enough for human times. You can also use timestamps `time.time()` or `elapsed = fpsClock.Tick(FPS)` for more accurate results.

Comment: so you are telling me that it is better to do a  time check for each cycle by running time.time() function and check whether the specified delay has passed, rather than reasoning on ticks?

Comment: It is more accurate, you call `start = time.time()` when you show the picture then on every cycle to check the elapsed time.

Comment: ok I see.
still, should I use the function fpsClock.Tick() to set a high rate of FPS in order to achieve a fast time sampling resolution?
I'll test the two different methods with LPT triggers and a diode linked to the EEG and report on the results ;)

Comment: You don't need a fast FPS, 10 or 15 should be fine, unless you're running animations.